# discord.py message counter not working

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a message counter with discord.py using the on_message event, but for some reason the counter just stays at 1 all the time, here is my code so you can have a better understanding on what I'm talking about.

```
@cord.event
async def on_message(message):
    global message_counter
    message_counter = 0
    message_counter += 1
```

Comment: You reset message_counter to 0 everytime. Just remove the line `message_counter = 0`.

Comment: Initialize `message_counter` somewhere else, not in `on_message`.

Comment: Well everytime I put it somewhere it just keeps saying `local variable 'message_counter' referenced before assignment`

Comment: oh wait I was able to make it work by not moving the line global variable line from the on_message event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use either the `global` or `nonlocal` declarations at the top of the function.

```
message_counter = 0

@cord.event
async def on_message(message):
    global message_counter
    message_counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You made the variable `message_counter` set to 0 every time someone speaks a message.

Try making it like this:

```
@cord.event
message_counter = 0
async def on_message(message):
    message_counter = message_counter + 1
```

Comment: You have a syntax error (the assignment needs to be above the decorator). Also, you have a scoping issue here.